# Tab contenteditable div marks beginning of text

Tags: angular, tabs

I'm creating an Angular 8 application where I've made a table using contenteditable divs which is filled with numbers.

When using tab to move over to the next cell it defaults puts the marker at the beginning of the value.

How do I make it so the marker selects the end of the value, or even better marks the whole value in next cell like ctrl A.

Also another question, how can I force when pressing Enter it acts like pressing Tab?

Best Regards

Comment: please add some code snippet to let other easily understand your problem and help you

Answer (score 0):

In bare js it would be done using this: `element.setSelectionRange(selectionStart, selectionEnd [, selectionDirection]);`

Regarding the Enter/tab key, I found this [article](https://briantjackett.com/2010/01/27/converting-an-enter-key-press-into-a-tab-key-press-for-web-forms/) that might be usefull since it's js at the end of the day, but it might cause problems if you want to work with forms.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for anyone that's interested.
Add this in your input div.

onfocus="requestAnimationFrame(() => document.execCommand('selectAll',false,null))"

This selects all the text when clicking the cell and also when using Tab.